How to validate token in ASP.NET Web API 2 on .NET 4.8 , we are not using middleware
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    //ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    //ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "", //some string, normally web url,  
                    ValidAudience = "",
                    //IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my_secret_key_12345"))
                }
            });

Note: in this code, I'm getting "not authenticated" error - please suggest a solution to get valid issuser and audience.
